# Difference between vegetales and verduras?

Tags: selección-de-palabras

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Vegetable”: verdura vs. vegetal](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/1151/vegetable-verdura-vs-vegetal)

My understanding is that they can both refer to "vegetables." But verduras also translates into "greens." So what's the difference?

Could it be that vegetales can also refer to "non-green" vegetables such as potatoes, mushrooms and (non-green) beans?

Comment: "Vegetales" is normally used for plants in general or plant related, like in "aceite vegetal". "Verduras" normally is used for edible vegetables.

Comment: I think it is a duplicate, and am closing it as such. However, Tom, if you feel you need additional clarification on some subtlety of the original question, please flag for moderator attention, and we can re-open this to address your additional question.

Comment: @Flimzy.  Could you put a link to the duplicated question?

Comment: @Paul: It's automatically added to the top of this question.

Comment: @Flimzy: Oops... I didn't notice it there. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Verduras* is a tiny subset of *vegetales*. Think of them as canidae (dogs, wolves, etc) and animals. In other words, all *verduras* are *vegetales*, but not all *vegetales* are *verduras*.

*Vegetales* is a type of organisms, as are animals, bacteriae, fungi, etc. You would say something has an *origen vegetal* when it was made from some kind of plant, such as olive oil, for example.

*Verduras* is a subtype, mostly something you can eat which is green colored. But not all *vegetales* you can eat are *verduras*.

Comment: Maybe is just my... mindset, but I also tend to think that "verduras" is something that you tend to cook (boil, mainly) before eating. **I** would never say that lechuga (*lettuce*) is a **verdura**... But maybe is just because of the way my mom used to call it... I totally agree with Jose J. Fernández, answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

There's an English word "produce"  (as in "the produce aisle of the supermarket").  I would translate "produce"  as "verduras".